# How can I check if a user has submitted a review?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Im super new to programming can anyone explain how I can check whether the currently logged in user has already submitted a review for a venue and if they have, hide the add review form?

**venue show.html.erb**

```
  <div id="reviews">
    <%= render :partial => 'reviews/review', :collection => @venue.reviews %>
  </div>

  <%= form_for [@venue, @review] do |f| %>
    <p>title: <br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %></p>

    <p>body: <br>
    <%= f.text_field :body %></p>

    <p>rating: <br>
    <%= f.text_field :rating %></p>

    <%= submit_tag %>
  <% end %>
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like

```
if current_user.reviews.where(:venue => @venue).any?
```